# Multithreaded synchronization primitive

Tags: parallel-processing, thread-safety, critical-section

I have the following scenario:

I have multiple worker threads running that all go through a certain section of code, and they're allowed to do so simultaneously. No critical section surrounds this piece of code right now as it's not required for these threads.

I have a main thread that also -occassionally- wants to enter that section of code, but when it does, none of the other worker threads should use that section of code.

Naive solution: surround the section of code with a critical section. But that would kill a lot of parallelism between the worker threads, which is important in my case.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Please explain clearly what are you trying to achieve and provide code sample of what you have so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RW locks. RW locks allow multiple readers and only a single writer. Your workers would call *read-lock* at the start of the critical section and the main thread would *write-lock*.

By definition, when calling *read-lock*, the calling process will wait for any writing threads to finish. When calling *write-lock*, the calling process will wait for any reading or writing threads to finish.

Example using POSIX threads:

```
pthread_rwlock_t lock;
/* worker threads */
void *do_work(void *args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&lock);
        // do some work...
        pthread_rwlock_unlock(&lock);
        sleep(1);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

/* main thread */
int main(void) {
    pthread_t workers[4];
    pthread_rwlock_init(&lock);
    int i;

    // spawn workers...
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        pthread_create(workers[i]; NULL, do_worker, NULL);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 100, ++i) {
        pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&lock);
        // do some work...
        pthread_rwlock_unlock(&lock);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me on my way.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand it, your worker threads are started asynchronously. So when the main thread wants to run this code section, you have to ensure that no worker thread is executing it. Therefore you have to stop all worker threads before the main thread can enter that code section, and allow them to enter it again afterwards.
This could be done - using Grand Central Dispatch - if your worker threads would be assigned to a dispatch group, see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html.
The main thread could then send the message `dispatch_group_wait` to this dispatch group, wait for all worker thread to leave this code section, execute it, and then requeue the worker threads.

Comment: To the one who down voted my answer: Could you please tell why? This is not only important for me (I want to learn something), but also for others who read this contribution...